# Why is acceptance prob $A(x \rightarrow x')=\min\left[1,\frac{\pi(x')Q(x'\rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x\rightarrow x')}\right]$ for Metropolis-Hastings?

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, monte-carlo, markov-process, metropolis-hastings

In the Metropolis-Hasting algorithm we choose the acceptance probability $A(x \rightarrow x')$ as following:

$$A(x \rightarrow x') = \min \left[1, \frac{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')} \right]$$

For me this formula is not 100% clear and would like to clarify why we need the min operator **and** the fractional part of the equation.

Let $T(x \rightarrow x')$ be the transition probability for our markov chains. Define it as follows wrt to the acceptance probability A and proposer probability Q:

$$T(x \rightarrow x') = Q(x \rightarrow x') A(x \rightarrow x')$$

$$T(x \rightarrow x) = Q(x \rightarrow x)+ \sum_{x \neq x'} Q(x \rightarrow x')(1- A(x \rightarrow x'))$$

Recall that the detailed balance equation (i.e. prob of going right is same as going left) is:

$$\pi(x)T(x \rightarrow x') =\pi(x')T(x' \rightarrow x)$$

Given that we have already chosen a (regular) proposal probability Q and that we want to define $T(x' \rightarrow x)$ to be stationary, then can just satisfy the detailed balance equation as follows (in the case of $x \neq x'$):

$$\pi(x)T(x \rightarrow x') =\pi(x')T(x' \rightarrow x)$$
$$\pi(x)A(x \rightarrow x')Q(x \rightarrow x') =\pi(x')A(x' \rightarrow x)Q(x' \rightarrow x)$$
$$\frac{A(x \rightarrow x')}{A(x' \rightarrow x)} = \frac{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')}$$

Which shows that we should choose the ratios of the $A's$ to be as above. Is the reason that we choose the min is to guarantee that the above ratio is always satisfied and therefore, that detailed balance is always satisfied?

Is the following reasoning correct:

Say that instead you **always** set $A(x \rightarrow x') = \frac{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')}$. Then if you consider the other acceptance transition direction $A(x' \rightarrow x) = \frac{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')}{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}$ must have reciprocal values. If that is the case, then one is larger than 1 and the other less than 1 (or both equal to 1 I guess). However, to satisfy:

$$\frac{A(x \rightarrow x')}{A(x' \rightarrow x)} = \frac{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')}$$

and having one of the acceptance direction be $A(x \rightarrow x') = \frac{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')}$, then the other **must** be 1 (otherwise $\frac{A(x \rightarrow x')}{A(x' \rightarrow x)} = \frac{\pi(x')Q(x' \rightarrow x)}{\pi(x)Q(x \rightarrow x')}$ would not be satisfied). Therefore, let the one that is less than 1 be the intended ratio and the other be 1. Thats what the min is doing. Right?

Is that the reason we have the min for 1? just to make sure the other direction is 1 and thus, satisfy detailed balance?

Answer (score 2):

$A(x \rightarrow x')$ is an acceptance probability, so it has to fit the [0, 1] range. But in practice it is not of much importance and can be omitted, like in an example of MH given by [Robert and Casella (2010)](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4419-1576-4):

```
y = geneq(x[t])
if ( runif(1) < f(y) * q(y, x[t]) / ( f(x[t]) * q(x[t], y) ) ) {
   x[t+1] = y
} else {
   x[t+1] =x[t]
}
```

where `geneq` is a generator for $q(y|x)$. As you can see, if writing it this way it doesn't matter if $A(x \rightarrow x')$ is less than one, while it works just the same like in the original formula.